# recover files from damaged windows 7 with ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, ubuntu-14.04

My windows 7 is damaged. I try to boot ubuntu from live USB to tranfers files from pc to an external hard drive but it is very slow transfer. Is this normal? I should install ubuntu instead of try ubuntu?
Is posible to install ubuntu on dual boot with a damaged windows?

Comment: _How_ slow is the transfer (in MB/s)? Do you know about the specs of the hard drives and the USB port connecting the external HD?

Comment: the speed is 50kb/s on USB 2.0 and 500kb/s on USB 3.0. I think this is very slow.

Answer (score 0):

If the source or target disk is damaged, then copying the files off will be slow and (very likely) incomplete.

Also, if the external disk is USB, this has a slower transfer speed than a normal disk (USB 3.0 is usually good enough, though).

Outside of that, it will depend on the tool you are using.  Typically, I find direct device copies with `dd` to be quicker than filesystem-aware tools (e.g. `cp`, `rsync`), especially if you use the `conv=sync,noerror` parameter to 'skip' areas of the source disk that can no longer be read.  Alternatively, `ddrescue` is a better command, if you have two external disks you can use (one for the recovered data and one for the transaction log file).

Another option is running GetDataBack from https://www.runtime.org/ on a bootable WinPE environment.  It costs money and takes some effort to setup (which may require you to use another machine to make a boot CD), but it has always worked well for me (albeit that it is also very slow on damaged disks).

I wouldn't attempt to install Ubuntu on the damaged disk unless you are absolutely sure that the disk already has an unused partition (or space for a partition) that you can install to, and that that area of the disk is not itself damaged -- you don't want to have to resize the Windows partition to fit the Ubuntu one (if the resize fails, you are left with few options for recovery).

In any case, your best option may be to go back to your most-recent backup.